# Why this switch/case statement doesn't work in Angular?

Tags: angular, switch-statement

I have a switch statement like this:

```
  switch (selectedValue1 ){
    case 'قطع از بالا':
      switch(selectedValue2){
        case 'سیگنال خرید':
          console.log(this.ngxService.period1);
          switch(this.ngxService.period1){
            case 6:
              console.log('This is case 6' , this.ngxService.period1);
```

The first log message works and I can see `6` in the console, but I don't know why I can't see the second log message and it doesn't work?

Comment: @Reactgular:I see  6

Comment: @Hasani is 6 a number or string?

Comment: I checked it by `console.log(typeof( this.ngxService.period1));` and it says it's string! But in my expression I defined it as `period:number` !

Comment: @ConnorsFan: No! The previous problem solved and this is new question.

Comment: Types only exist at compilation time. If this comes from the server for example (we're making assumptions here, hint hint), and the server sends you a string, nothing at runtime will tell you that it's supposed to be a number. Also, what's wrong with `if` and `&&`?

Comment: @JBNizet: So how should I convert it to a number in my `switch` statements? Or it's better to use `case "6" `?

Comment: It would be better to 1. fix the type or the code producing this value 2. avoid using magical values like that, and define constants or a union type. But what best to do is really hard to say with so few information about what these values are, where they come from, what your code is, etc.

Comment: Please don't ask these kinds of questions. Double check your source code for typos, syntax mistakes and you could have saved people time by using a `debugger;` just *once* before asking a question. You asked two *typo* questions within 15 minutes. Slow down and check your work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a string: `this.ngxService.period1`, then change it to number:

```
switch(Number(this.ngxService.period1))
```

6 as string value does not match the case 6 which is number as they are two different types. Cast the 6 string to a number.

Comment: Is it better to convert it to number or just use `case "6": ` instead?

Comment: @Hasani It depends but if you are sure you always get number here: `this.ngxService.period1` then cast it to a number. If you are getting nonnumerical values also like `six` then use `case '6':`